# Bash help: awk columns

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, awk

```
       120          ,     3     <IP address>   <port>   
       100          ,     3     xx.xxx.xx.xxx  xxxx      
       220          ,     3     xxx.xx.xxx.xxx  xxxx  
       280                3     xx.xxx.xx.xxx   xx
```

Hey guys, I'm working on a shell script and trying to grep/awk/sed some IP addresses. Cleaing up the output is tricky. Notice the bottom line doesn't have a  `,`. I'm trying to do soemthing like `$ awk '{print $4, $5}'` to filter out the IP and port columns but that won't work with the bottom line.

Feels like I'm going about this the wrong way. How can I filter out just the IP and port colomuns?

Comment: Are the columns separated by tabs or spaces?

Comment: Hey! Separated by spaces.

Comment: Hey there, are you still looking for an answer that properly addresses your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since the columns are invariant, you could `cut -c32-` (`man cut`) the file.

Answer (score 0):

As always in Linux there's more than one way to get the job done. I've placed the text you provided into a `file.txt`. Here are two possible ways based on the information you've given:

#### 1. awk solution: Use awk's NF variable  to start from the last field

```
linux-okrz:~# awk '{print $(NF-1), $(NF)}' file.txt
address> <port>
xx.xxx.xx.xxx xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx xx
```

#### 2. sed solution: Use sed to remove the comma before-hand

```
linux-okrz:~# sed 's|,||g' file.txt | awk '{print $3, $4}'
<IP address>
xx.xxx.xx.xxx xxxx
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx xxxx
xx.xxx.xx.xxx xx
```

Note that in both examples the first line is slightly off because there is a space between "IP" and "address". Assuming that in the real output it is an actual IP address that shouldn't be a problem. Also, the second example may not work if you have other instances in the output with which there is an important comma that is needed.

Lastly, these commands are based solely on the output and question provided. It could be that further tweaking would be needed depending on what else is in the file and/or what else you are doing in your script.

Comment: I came here to write about $NF, but saw it was already done! :) However, the use of `cat` in this context is unnecessary, http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat

Comment: Good point @mgor. Old habits die hard I s'pose. Corrected my answer to  be more process sensitive. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using grep:

```
grep -Po '(\d+\.){3}\d+\s+\d+'
```